# Collect value that is below other values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to figure out how to collect the value that is always in `LINE 9` of texts with this same template:

```
Aposta
Sport: 11.718.177
Compartilhar
Feita por 
Privado
em 25/06/2021 às 10:04
Vitória
10:04 25/06/2021
Katerina Siniakova - Sorribes Tormo, Sara
2nd set jogo 6 - vencedor

Vitória
Katerina Siniakova
1,30
2-0
```

In this case, the value of `LINE 9` is:

`Vitória`

I tried to use:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,"
"))
```

And after creating a column with the separate values, I tried using `QUERY` to remove the first lines of text and using `LIMIT 9` to keep only the value of `ROW 9`, but `QUERY` joins the values from other lines and ends up giving a wrong value.

**Note: I will need to use it to analyze texts like this on several different lines in `Column A`, so I should look for an option that can also be used as `ARRAY` so I don't need to put a different formula on each line.**

Comment: Looks to me like the target line is line 12, not line 9.

Comment: Hi Erik, two blank lines at the beginning of the text, a few more lines of text and after ```em 25/06/2021 às 10:04``` it is ```Vitória```

Comment: I see. I was looking at the second instance of `Vitória`. Looks like Matt's got you sorted with his formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the 9th column of an array split by carriage returns:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A,CHAR(10),0,0),,9)
```